# Get shared_ptr by reference with dynamic_pointer_cast

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

Is it ok to get the return value from `dynamic_pointer_cast` by reference, or can it cause problem?

```
struct A
{
};

struct B : public A
{
};

int main()
{
  shared_ptr<A> b = make_shared<B>();
  auto &a = dynamic_pointer_cast<A>(b);
  //auto a = dynamic_pointer_cast<A>(b);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The question is: why do you *want* to get a reference?

Comment: So the reference counter is not increased

Comment: This would defeat the purpose of using a smart pointer because you'd introduce the possibility of a dangling reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if it *were* possible, it wouldn’t do what you want:

> [The aim is that] the reference counter is not increased

It *would still be increased* since `dynamic_pointer_cast` returns a *new* `shared_ptr` copy anyway.

Your code doesn’t work since the reference would then be bound to the temporary object returned by the `dyanamic_pointer_cast` and this is forbidden.

Using a `const` reference would work (since `const&` is allowed to bind to a temporary) but the result would still be the same: the cast would create a *new* instance of a `shared_ptr`, and increment the reference count.